# Polymorphic show many items

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, polymorphism

I am trying to create a polymorphic relationships and to show them.

Here my relationships

```
events
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
users
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
comments
  belongs_to :comments, :polymorphic => true
```

comments has the following models

```
#  commentable_id   :integer
#  commentable_type :string(255)
```

Now my goals would be show on event#index items related to the events but also to shows all comments.description according to each events sorta has follow

```
*********************         *********************
Event.title                   Event.title
Event.description             Event.description
{Comment.body}                {Comment.body}   
...                           ...                     
**********************        **********************
```

and so on.

Here my controller

```
def index
    @mosttop = Event.all[1..-1]
    @loc = @mosttop.comments
end
```

If i do this however i get an undefined locations. I am wondering what i am doing wrong. Also, my routes is has follow

```
resources :events do
  resources :comments do
end
```

Also at the moment I haven't create a relationship using build, but just when at the link `event/1/comments` and create it

the controller is has follow

```
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    ...
   end

  private

    def load_commentable
      resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
      @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    end
  end
```

Comment: are you mistake? `belongs_to :commentable`, not `belongs_to :comments`. `Event.all[1..-1]` return a list of object, not one object, so you cannot use `mosttop.comments`

Comment: In your case, I think you just need setup `has_many :through` association. Event has many comments, User has many comments, Comments belongs to Event, Comments belongs to User, that's it.

Comment: What would be the point of polymorphic at this point then? Thank you for your respond

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand about polymorphic. If you use polymorphic, comments only can belongs to event or user, but in your case, you need to know comments belongs to both event and user. Example if one row in your comments table only have commentable_id is id of event, how do you know that comment belongs to whom? And in case user is similar, how do i know user commented for which event, if i only have commentable_id is user_id?

Comment: Oh so its only when either one of them but not both included! Thank you!!!

Comment: Your association is simple, if you want both of them you should used belongs_to as i commented above.